# How to Print PDF in Safari using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, macos, printing, safari, macos-big-sur

I have a PDF open in Safari that I want to print.
How do I display the print dialog using JavaScript?

I tried using `window.print()` but that causes the Safari tab to freeze and does not bring up the print dialog. It works in other browsers (Firefox / Chrome) but I'm not sure if this ever worked in Safari.

`document.execCommand('print', false, null);` gave the same results (Safari tab seems to freeze)

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Open any PDF in Safari (eg. https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf)
2. Open console and enter `window.print()` or `document.execCommand('print', false, null);`
3. No print dialog is displayed and the browser tab now seems to freeze (eg. PDF contents don't react to window resizing).

It feels like Safari thinks the print dialog is open and is blocking the thread, but nothing shows up visually.

Safari Version: 14.1.1 (16611.2.7.1.4)
macOS Version: Big Sur (11.4)

Comment: I just tried and for me, it worked `window.print()`, but I tried it on older version of Big Sur and Safari

Comment: I've tried it on another machine running the same versions of Safari and macOS and was able to reproduce it. Maybe it's a bug that was introduced recently.

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility. check once it on the apple support forum in case someone has already reported it.

Comment: @NikhilSingh What version of macOS and Safari are you running?

Comment: OS - 11.2.3 and Safari - 14.0.3

Comment: Was this raised/is there any updated?

Comment: I posted it to the apple forum [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252821086).
The answer wasn't very helpful.